# Displaying argv when called through a function - conflicting types ?

Tags: c, argv

I want to create a small program that will print the args that are passed through the command line. If there is the option -i, it should print them backwards.

Here is what I have so far

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void usage ();
int option_i(char *);
void display_argv(char *, int);
void display_argv_backwards(char *, int);

int main(int argc,  char * argv[]) {
    if (argc == 1) { usage();};

    int reverse = option_i(argv[1]) ;

    if (reverse) {display_argv_backwards(* argv, argc);} else {display_argv(* argv, argc);}

    return 0 ; }

void usage (){ printf("%s\n", "arg < 1 ?" ); exit(1);}

int option_i(char *mot) { return mot[0] == '-' && mot[1] == 'i' ; }

void display_argv(char argv, int argc){
    int k = 0;
    while(k < argc) {printf("%s\n", argv[k++] );};

}

void display_argv_backwards( char * argv, int argc){printf("%s\n", "backwards");}
```

But I can't manage to figure out how to print the arg in my function display_argv. I have tried many different ways, but it seems like I'm getting confused about what is passed through the function.

Current mistakes:

```
error: conflicting types for ‘display_argv’
 void display_argv(char  argv, int argc){
      ^
cx11.0.c:6:6: note: previous declaration of ‘display_argv’ was here
 void display_argv(char *, int);
      ^
cx11.0.c: In function ‘display_argv’:
cx11.0.c:24:38: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
  while(k < argc) {printf("%s\n", argv[k++] );};
```

Thanks for shedding any light on my issues.

Comment: `void display_argv(char *, int);
void display_argv_backwards(char *, int);` --> `void display_argv(char **, int);
void display_argv_backwards(char **, int);`...`display_argv_backwards(* argv, argc);} else {display_argv(* argv, argc);` --> `display_argv_backwards(argv, argc);} else {display_argv( argv, argc);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : Why " * * " when defining the function ? These changes don't seem to solve anything.

Comment: Because it is `int main (int argc, char **argv)`  (which is in reality what happens when `*argv[]` is passed as a parameter to a function) See §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup C11 Standard. (and particularly *note: 10*) concerning `argc` and `argv`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: could you elaborate on your answer? I don't get it.

Comment: Sure, the declaration for `main` is `int main (int argc, char *argv[])`. Where `*argv[]` is an *array of pointers to type char*. When any array is passed as a parameter to a function, the first level of indirection, (e.g. the first `[]`) is converted to *a pointer*. Thus when passed to a function `char *argv[]` is converted to `char **argv`. So when you pass `argv` to `display_argv` and `display_argv_backwards` the type is `char **`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, and in addition to it, you are going to drive yourself nuts if you try and force all your code-blocks to fit on one line. Go ahead and properly space and indent your code. Sure, one liners for minimal block content is fine (e.g. `if (argc == 1) usage();`), but for the remainder, move the body to the next line and use braces as required.

For example, you can open your code up a bit with something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void usage (void);
int option_i (char *);
void display_argv (char **, int);
void display_argv_backwards (char **, int);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc == 1) usage();

    int reverse = option_i (argv[1]) ;

    if (reverse) 
        display_argv_backwards (argv, argc);
    else
        display_argv (argv, argc);

    return 0;
}

void usage (void)
{ 
    printf("%s\n", "arg < 1 ?" );
    exit(1);
}

int option_i (char *mot) 
{ 
    return mot[0] == '-' && mot[1] == 'i'; 
}

void display_argv (char **argv, int argc)
{
    int k = 0;
    while (k < argc)
        printf ("%s\n", argv[k++]);
}

void display_argv_backwards (char **argv, int argc)
{
    printf("%s\n", "backwards");
    while (argc--)
        printf ("%s\n", argv[argc]);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/argcvdisp
arg < 1 ?

$ ./bin/argcvdisp foo bar baz
./bin/argcvdisp
foo
bar
baz

$ ./bin/argcvdisp -i foo bar baz
backwards
baz
bar
foo
-i
./bin/argcvdisp
```

Now, granted, much of the formatting and indentation is *style*, and to a large extent, that is up to you and a matter of personal choice. However, for anyone reading your code, there are certain "coding standards" for style that help with readability and ultimately maintainability of your code. One such reference is [**NASA C Style Guide**](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/pm/Papers/nasa-c-style.pdf) (Goddard Spaceflight Center 1994).

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to improve the formatting of my code in the future. The char ** is still not crystal clear to me, but I will look into it.

Comment: It's one of those things that is "*just the way it is*", It is a rule in C that applies to arrays passed as a parameter to a function. For example take the character array `char string[] = "my string";` When you pass the array `string` as a parameter to a function `string` is converter to a pointer to the first element of the array, e.g. `(char *string)`. If you have `int array[2][5];` you would pass `(int (*array)[5])`. There are other subtleties to the rule, but that is the crux of it. There are **many, many** questions and answer here that discuss it `:)`